# Arduino and Java

Tags: java, arduino

When I send data with Arduino to Java programm, I use jssc library. In older version Arduino it work nice, but when I use Arduino with ATmega 328 microcontroller in java respond data three parting, for example Arduino send 1234567, but java take data like 
123
45
67
in one sicle
have a decision for it?

Comment: You should use buffering to receive data or check for data termination. Java program will receive data as it comes depending on buffers, hardware you are using. So when you read data it comes in chunks and you need to collect all chunks to restore original data packet.

Comment: You were never guarantied, that you will get the message in a single chunk. Your code should work even if you get data byte by byte.